# JavaFX ComboBox selection bug

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, combobox

I always seem to have an issue with ComboBox controls in JavaFX whereby sometimes when I select an item I get an error such as:

```
Mar 02, 2016 1:01:34 PM com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow addTrailingCells
INFO: index exceeds maxCellCount. Check size calculations for class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin$4$1
```

The only way I've found of fixing this is to use the setVisibleRowCount to be one less than the number of populated items, e.g. if there's 5 items, I set the visible row count to 4. If there are only 2 items however then I have to set it to 1, which is not particularly pleasing from a UI interactivity point of view.

I'm not sure if setting the visible row count is the actual fix, whether there's something else I can do to fix it, or indeed why this bug is happening. Can anyone help?

UPDATE: I was running Jdk8 Update 51 when I had this bug. Having now just updated to Jdk8 Update 73, the bug no longer exists. Furthermore, previously with update 51 when I first opened a ComboBox it had a scrollbar by default, that would disappear after it had been opened twice. As of update 73, this no longer happens, and it does not have a scrollbar by default. I think this may have been what the bug was related to.

Is anyone able to confirm this and also that my observation of the update change is indeed the case?

Comment: Do you have a code running when the selected item changes? Something that alters the list of items, perhaps? The JavaFX ComboBox seems to be very sensitive to such changes. If you do have something like that, providing the relevant code may help suggest ways to solve it.

Comment: can u share code in short.

Comment: This has nothing to do with code running - it happens for me whenever I have a ComboBox, that is say for example populated with some hard-coded items from an ObservableList.

Comment: I am pretty certain this has something to do with how the ComboBox initially appears with a scrollbar and then later often decides to remove the scrollbar. I think it may be something to do with selecting an item at the point at which it decides to remove the scrollbar?

Answer (score 0):

The following is just a small hack to be able to stop warning from showing up in JavaFX.

```
combo.setVisibleRowCount(<size of list> -1)
```

This will reduce the viewable window size, but if your list is longer than 2, this will not significantly impact the aesthetics of your program.

NOTE: This fix was originally posted a few months ago. Unfortunately, I was not able to find the reference at this time.